# Bootstrap 3 Collapse - must remain open this panel

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have [site](http://my.sdudorm.kz) . In the left menu have category make with panel collapse(bootstrap). Question: How to do when choosing a category, this panel must be open. Panel closed because page updated.
This is code of panel:

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2">Электрика</a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="list-group">
    <?php foreach ($categories2 as $categoryItem): ?>
      <li class="list-group-item">
          <a href="/category2/<?php echo $categoryItem['id'];?>" class="list2">
            <p style="text-align: left; height: 5px;"><?php echo $categoryItem['name'];?></p>
          </a>
      </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

js code for active class and for open panel:

```
var $dropdowns = $('.list-group-item');
var $collapse = $('.panel-collapse');
$dropdowns.click(function() {
  if ( $(this).hasClass('active') ){
     $(this).toggleClass('active');
     $collapse.show();
  }else {
     $dropdowns.removeClass('active');
     $(this).toggleClass('active');
  }});
```

Comment: what are you using to load your pages? is it PHP? if so, you would first need to obtain your URL in order to see what page you are on. The way you have it right now wont work because once your page reloads, that click action becomes obsolete. What you need to do is first obtain your URL, then build a conditional that makes them active if the url matches your condition.

Comment: you can also use PHP to check if your URL matches.. something like `if $url === 'page1' add active class, else keep inactive`

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for your URL on every page load. You can do this using PHP, and deciding whether or not to add the active class. The active class in bootstrap seems to be `in`. I would just modify one line of code as follows:

```
<div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse <?= ($url === "page1")?"in":"" ?>" aria-expanded="true">
```

`$url` represents the current uri your trying to obtain like www.example.com/**page1** ,the uri can be obtained by `$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.  The rest is just simple ternary operator to shorten up the if conditional.

Answer (score -1):

To show menu as expended add ***"in"*** class and one extra attribute 
***aria-expanded="true"***

```
<div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse in" aria-expanded="true">
```

So the sample code will be.

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2">Электрика</a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse in" aria-expanded="true">
    <ul class="list-group">
    <?php foreach ($categories2 as $categoryItem): ?>
      <li class="list-group-item">
          <a href="/category2/<?php echo $categoryItem['id'];?>" class="list2">
            <p style="text-align: left; height: 5px;"><?php echo $categoryItem['name'];?></p>
          </a>
      </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: What he asked is the menu need to be active once he visited the category page. The code you posted won't make the menu active

Answer (score -1):

> Add JS id for your menu link which is supposed to be open on page load ( or to be default open)

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2" id="click_menu">Электрика</a>
```

Call below JS function on page load

```
function default_menu_selection() {
   $("#click_menu").trigger('click')
}
```

> This will open the menu on page refresh

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/